# Cron-Job / Backup entire Ubuntu System with tar, atfer this rsync this archive

Tags: cron, rsync, tar

I want to create the cron-job for the following steps:

1. Backup my entire ubuntu server with the following command:

> tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/dev --exclude=/sys /

2. after the backup in the archive is finished i want to rsync the archive with the following command:

> sudo rsync -avz /backup.tar.gz -e "ssh -i /path/.ssh/ssh-key -p Port" backup@xxx.xxx:/path/path/path

Can we set a cron-job for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not?
Create a batch script with the commands you know are working

```
echo "#!/bin/bash" >> /usr/bin/local/backup.sh
echo "tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/dev --exclude=/sys /" >> /usr/bin/local/backup.sh
echo "sudo rsync -avz /backup.tar.gz -e "ssh -i /path/.ssh/ssh-key -p Port" backup@xxx.xxx:/path/path/path" >> /usr/bin/local/backup.sh
chmod +x /usr/bin/local/backup.sh
```

Then test it

```
/usr/bin/local/backup.sh
```

If you are happy [add it as a cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can, for example, write a bash script which you then will set up in crontab to be run every X hours, minutes, days or weeks etc.

Comment: You read my post complete? I know how to set a cronjob daily, weekly or other. But i ask for set it to wait for the first job.

Comment: you write a **script** that runs one command then the next. There is not "wait until after" for cron commands.